# Do not encode UTF-8 characters in the query parameter in an http request

Tags: excel, vba, http, ms-access, gmail-api

My English is from Google Translate, so sorry if it's not clear enough.

I'm using Tim Hall's WebRequest class to make http requests.
By default it encodes UTF-8 characters that are in the URL, in general this is correct behavior, but when I want to load from the gmail api messages from the email box that contain a specific label, and the name of the label is in Hebrew, I must pass in the query parameter of the URL the name of the label in Hebrew, Otherwise gmail doesn't find a match, and returns me 0 results.

I tried to make the same request with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0, where the address is not encoded and it did solve the problem.
However, I would like to be able to do this with WebRequest because the entire structure of my application includes handling all types of http request errors already built on WebRequest.

So in conclusion, the question is whether it is possible to prevent WebRequest from encoding the URL

This is my code:

```
Dim request As New WebRequest
pGmailClient.BaseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/"
request.Resource = "users/{userId}/messages"
request.AddUrlSegment "userId", "me"
request.AddQuerystringParam "q", "label:(בדיקה) is:(unread)"
request.AddHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & pGmailClient.Authenticator.Token

Dim response As WebResponse
Set response = pGmailClient.Execute(request)
```

Here is the source of WebRequest:
[WebRequest](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)

Comment: Have you tried something like `request.Resource = "users/{userId}/messages?q=label:(בדיקה) is:(unread)` ?   Maybe just encode the space / parentheses

Comment: it worked!
I've been trying to solve this for several hours without success, I didn't think of this simple and genius solution!
Write it as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

`request.Resource = "users/{userId}/messages?q=label:(בדיקה) is:(unread)` ?

Maybe just encode the space / parentheses

Perhaps also look at this, which may be relevant here?  [Gmail API not respecting UTF encoding in subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695749/gmail-api-not-respecting-utf-encoding-in-subject)